# Is it possible to make a decimal variable with a 0 in front of it in Python 3?

Tags: python, decimal

I am working on a project which requires the variable, `s`, to be equal to `01234567`. However, whenever I try to run the program, it always says

`leading zeros in decimal literals are not permitted; use an 0o prefix for octal integers`. It is necessary that s starts with a zero; is there any way to bypass this error?

```py
k = list(int(input("What is the key? "))) # asks user for key
s = 01234567 # state to shuffle the numbers
# this line above is where the error takes place

#still a work in progress
def hash(s, k):
    i = 0
    j = 0
    for i < 8:
        j = (j + s(i) + k(i % 5)) % 8 # % performs mod
        # j makes a new j variable
        s(i), s(j) = s(j), s(i) # swaps the two variable values

hash (s, k) # hashes
```

Comment: Why is it necessary for the number to start with a zero? Do you want to print it or write it to a file with the zero? If so, you should add the zero when printing/writing.

Comment: Can you describe your initial problem? Looking at your hash code, you want `s` to be a an array, not a number.

Comment: You should probably use `s = list(range(8))` if you need 0 through 7. `for i < 8` is incorrect syntax. It should be `if i < 8`. If you are using `s(i)` to index `s`, then it should be `s[i]`.

Comment: This is definitely an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/248627).

Comment: Ummm ... if the project requires a numerical value to have a leading 0, then the specifications are faulty.  `012` and `12` are the *same* integer value; there cannot be any difference in their programmatic representation.  **However**, your coding suggests that you do *not* require a *decimal* value; rather, you're dealing with a sequence of single digits, either integer or string.  You need to change your code to deal with that usage.

Comment: "requires the variable, `s`, to be equal to `01234567`" That requirement doesn't make any sense. `01234567` isn't a valid literal in Python, so you need to be more explicit about what exactly you mean... what is `01234567` **supposed to represent**? an `int`?

Comment: @arthasastra7 If my answer helped you, please see [how does accepting an answer work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, You should have `k` and `s` be a list of integers. Strings are not mutable, so you won't be able to edit them in place. Also, you need to index with square brackets (`[]`). You can't index with parenthesis (`()`).  Altogether:

```
k = [int(c) for c in input("What is the key? ")] # asks user for key
s = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7] # state to shuffle the numbers
# this line above is where the error takes place

#still a work in progress
def hash(s, k):
    i = 0
    j = 0
    for i in range(8):
        j = (j + s[i] + k[i % 5]) % 8 # % performs mod
        # j makes a new j variable
        s[i], s[j] = s[j], s[i] # swaps the two variable values

hash (s, k) # hashes

print (s)
```

Finally, you may want to check that k has a length of at least 5 to prevent an indexing error.